# Weapon class and character subclass choices

Tags: destiny

Would I get more damage from a solar weapon if my character also having a solar subclass?

Comment: Weapons can benefit from subclasses, and subclasses can benefit from weapons. What subclass you are using, and the weapons you use make a bit of a difference on the answer

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. It seems a very precise easily answerable question...

Answer (score 3):

If your question is:

"Does a Solar Subclass inherently get a bouns to Solar damage?", the answer is:

**No**, Destiny does not give inherent bonuses in that fashion.